# Will peaches on a sapling grow into mature fruit?

Tags: fruit-trees, peaches

I planted this peach sapling in mid April in Western New York:

[image]

It's about 3 and a half feet tall. It's planted in an area that yields about 8 hours a day of direct sunlight and we have been watering it every few days since planting it. The nursery that sold it to us said it likely wouldn't yield fruit for a few years. But in the last week, these little walnut-sized fruits have sprouted!

[image]

Forgive my ignorance, but can we expect these to grow into mature, edible fruit from a sapling? They told us years and it sprouts fruit in a matter of weeks? I feel like I'm missing something.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We often see fruit, small or full size, on saplings sold by garden centres, and these are surprisingly small trees.

If the tree can't support the fruit, they'll just drop off. But if you want to give it the best shot of getting larger fruit, you should probably remove half the fruit at each location.

Answer (score 7):

They will most probably yield some fruit, which may be edible - it probably won't grow very large.

There is also a school of thought which says its better - long term - for you to remove these fruit so the plant can concentrate on growing.